# or we will/would .

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I'm wondering whether "will" or "would" should be used in the following, and why:

> Our water has frozen. We should heat it, or we will/would have nothing to drink.

> When we go shopping, we have to carry our IDs, or the police will/would take us to the police office.

Answer (score 1):

These are facts - if you don't melt some ice you *will* have nothing to drink. In your country, if you don't carry your ID you *will* be arrested.

However, they could be turned into hypothetical statements.

If we *were to* leave the water frozen we *would* have nothing to drink.

If we *were to* go out without our IDs the police *would* arrest us.

Comment: Are you suggesting both options are possible in the OP?

Comment: No - the way you have written the sentences, they are statements of fact, not conditionals. If you wanted to use 'would', you _would_ have to turn the sentences into conditionals.

Comment: How about "I had to defend myself, or else he’d have killed me"?

Comment: "...or else he would have killed me" - _or else_ implies _if I had not defended myself_.

Comment: Could the "else" be omitted?

Comment: Yes, it could be - but we're straying into a different question here!

Comment: If "I had to defend myself, or he’d have killed me" is okay with a conditioal, why are the sentences in the OP not okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120571/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-apollyon).